# Converting a set of inequalities into a linear program

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

> Consider a polyhedron defined on the following set of constraints:
>
> $$x_1+2x_2-2 \leq 0$$ $$-x_1 \leq 0 $$ $$ -x_1+x_2-1 \leq 0$$ $$ x_1 +
>  x_2 -1 \leq 0$$

I want to convert it the standard LP form (which is possibly):

$$ \min c^T x $$
$$ \text{s.t.} \ \  Ax \leq b$$
$$ x \geq 0$$

I know how to find the constraint $Ax\leq b$. But what is the objective function here?

Answer (score 3):

It's not given in the information provided.

If it is not of interest to optimize anything in particular, for example, if your interest is to check if the feasible set is non-empty, you can just pick $c$ to be the zero vector to make every feasible point optimal.